# Get the row that has been clicked in the gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have added OnClick event dynamically for gridview.So when I click on any of the row on grid view, the event is fired but I can't get which row is clicked.
This is the code where I add event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Attributes["OnClick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(btnGrid, string.Empty);

}
```

//This is the code which catches this event

```
protected void GridView1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _ID="10" //Static data. I need this from the gridview1.row[ClickedRow].cell[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear you'll have to "manually" assign this value.

For this, add hidden input element to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="clicked_row" />
```

Change the code to:

```
e.Row.Attributes["OnClick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(btnGrid, string.Empty) + "; document.forms[0].elements['clicked_row'].value = '" + e.Row.RowIndex + "';";
```

And finally, read the index from the Request in the `GridView1_OnClick` method:

```
_ID = Int32.Parse(Request.Form["clicked_row"]);
```

If each row has its own ID change `e.Row.RowIndex` to `e.Row.Id`.

Comment: ...As like _ID, I need total four values from four different columns.. So how can I modify your code??

Comment: Just take them directly from the grid, with the proper row at hand you can read any other values from that row.

Comment: I mean something like `string myText = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Text` that will take the text of second column in selected row of the GridView.

Comment: I don't know. Guess that in `GridView1_OnClick`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you could pass your id/rowindex as parameter to `GetPostBackClientHyperlink()` and implement the `IPostBackEventHandler`-interface in your page. The `RaisePostBackEvent()` method will get the id as input parameter passed in.

I haven't tested this, I just took a look at the example in [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms153108.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the row instead of the grid, like this:

```
e.Row.Attributes["OnClick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(e.Row, String.Empty);
```

And in your event handler:

```
protected void GridView1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    if (sender is GridViewRow)
    {
         int index = ((GridViewRow)sender).RowIndex;
    }
}
```

I'm not positive, but I think the GridView OnClick will still fire since you're passing a child element of the grid.